Residue of $\tan(z)$
I do not understand why the residue of $\tan(z)$ at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$ should be -1 and not -$i$. I write $\tan(z)$ as follows:
\begin{equation*}
\tan(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}
\end{equation*}
then I write the Taylor series of $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$ at $z=\frac{\pi}{2}$:
\begin{equation*}
e^{iz}+e^{-iz}=i-i+(z-\frac{\pi}{2})(-1-1)+\frac{1}{2}(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^2(-i+i)+(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^3R_3(z)
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{equation*}
\tan(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{(z-\frac{\pi}{2})(-2+(z-\frac{\pi}{2})^3R_3(z))}
\end{equation*}
thus the residue should be:
\begin{equation*}
Res_{z=\pi/2}(\tan(z))=\frac{e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}-e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}}{-2}=\frac{2i}{-2}=-i
\end{equation*}
What am I missing??

You forgot an $i$ in the exponential expression for $\tan(z)$, since $\sin={e^{iz}-e^{-iz} \over 2i}$, so, yes, the $2$ cancels that in the analogous expression for $\cos(z)$, but the $i$ is left over, in the denominator. :)

check your definition of $tan(z)$

Okk, thank you!

This question is similar to: What is the residue of $f(z)=\tan{z}$ at any of its pole ? Is the solution correct?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Easier method: $\tan z=\sin z/\cos z$, so the residue is $\sin z/\cos'z=\sin z/(-\sin z)=-1$.  There are conditions to be checked in order to use this method but I will leave that up to you.

You have the wrong expression for $\tan(z)$. It should be:
$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$
$$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
Of course, $\tan=\frac{\sin}{\cos}$ therefore:
$$\tan(z)=\frac{i(e^{-iz}-e^{iz})}{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}$$
Now try finding the residue at $z=\frac\pi2$

What is the reason for a downvote?
